# How to set a generic member variable in a derived class with a specific generic type

Tags: c#, generics

I have a base class (BaseClass below) which has a member variable that is also a base class (BaseGeneric<BaseWidget> Generic below) and is generic. I want derived classes of BaseClass to supply a concrete instance in this variable. But I get a compiler error when the derived class tries to assign the concrete instance.

The error is "Cannot implicitly convert type 'DerivedGeneric' to 'BaseGeneric<BaseWidget>'".

```
class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    // the compiler likes this (obviously)
    public override BaseWidget Widget => new DerivedWidget();

    // and this
    public override IEnumerable<object> Objects => (IEnumerable<object>)new List<int>();

    // but doesn't like this even though DerivedGeneric : BaseGeneric<DerivedWidget> 
    public override BaseGeneric<BaseWidget> Generic => new DerivedGeneric();

    // nor does it like this.
    public override BaseGeneric<BaseWidget> BonusGeneric => (BaseGeneric<BaseWidget>)new DerivedGeneric();
}

abstract class BaseClass
{
    public abstract BaseWidget Widget { get; }

    public abstract IEnumerable<object> Objects { get; }

    public abstract BaseGeneric<BaseWidget> Generic { get; }

    public abstract BaseGeneric<BaseWidget> BonusGeneric { get; }
}

class BaseWidget { }

class DerivedWidget : BaseWidget { }

abstract class BaseGeneric<T> where T : BaseWidget { }

class DerivedGeneric : BaseGeneric<DerivedWidget> { }
```

This surprises me since I would think DerivedGeneric is a BaseGeneric<DerivedWidget> and DerivedWidget is a BaseWidget so DerivedGeneric is a BaseGeneric<BaseWidget>.

This is with .NET 6.

Comment: [Covariance and contravariance in generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance).

Comment: You could potentially look into using a covariant interface for `BaseGeneric` depending on how it needs to be used.

Comment: I think that will work for me. Thanks @JohnathanBarclay!

Answer (score 0):

Solution changing BaseGeneric to a covariant interface, courtesy of @JohnathanBarclay.

```
class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    // the compiler likes this (obviously)
    public override BaseWidget Widget => new DerivedWidget();

    // and this,
    public override IEnumerable<object> Objects => (IEnumerable<object>)new List<int>();

    // and this,
    public override IBaseGeneric<BaseWidget> Generic => new DerivedGeneric();

    // and this!
    public override IBaseGeneric<BaseWidget> BonusGeneric => (IBaseGeneric<BaseWidget>)new DerivedGeneric();
}

abstract class BaseClass
{
    public abstract BaseWidget Widget { get; }

    public abstract IEnumerable<object> Objects { get; }

    public abstract IBaseGeneric<BaseWidget> Generic { get; }

    public abstract IBaseGeneric<BaseWidget> BonusGeneric { get; }
}

class BaseWidget { }

class DerivedWidget : BaseWidget { }

interface IBaseGeneric<out T> where T : BaseWidget { }

class DerivedGeneric : IBaseGeneric<DerivedWidget> { }
```